# Using the .weekday() function in calendar but the input values come in MM/DD/YYYY rather than YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: python, string, calendar, int

The weekday function only accepts integer values so i cant just concatenate string values and ',' seperators. I have to somehow concatenate string values and transform them to an integer value.

The .weekday() function in calendar only accepts int values and the format YYYY,MM,DD. I need to convert my input which has the values "DD MM YYYY" into this format.

```
 import calendar
inputdate ="08 05 2015"


MM=inputdate[:2]
DD=inputdate[3:5]
YY=inputdate[6:10]
MM=MM.lstrip('0')
DD=DD.lstrip('0')
int(MM)
int(DD)
int(YY)
print(YY+MM+DD)
date=calendar.weekday(YY,MM,DD)


print(date)
```

the logic of above is what i want to achieve but i dont know how to concatentate mismatching datatypes.

Comment: please add more information or explanation

Comment: I've updated the code somewhat so its somewhat more readable let me know if you need more information still.

Comment: would adding `str()` around `YY`, `MM` and `DD` work? This would convert them to strings allowing you to concatenate with other strings using `+`.  You can't concatenate int and strings.

Comment: Yeah, going to need far more information on what you are trying to do. First of all the int() function doesn't just magically make an int when you place characters like ',' in it.  datecheck = int(str(YY) + str(MM) +str(DD)) would get you a joined int  but other than that not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: For example if i input this date=calendar.weekday(2018, 3, 3) i get no errors and the value returns as expected. But when i enter date=calendar.weekday("2018", "3", "3") it doesn't work. Same with date=calendar.weekday("2018, 3, 3"). So what i want to know is if its possible to get a whole variable with different datatypes contained within it. with "," str values mixed with int values.

Comment: No, you can't mix the data types, why do you need to?

Comment: Because the argument requires ',' between integers so i was wondering how i would achieve this format without mixing data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `+','`'s in your weekday line like so:
`calendar.weekday(YY, MM, DD)`

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday)

Full Code:

```
import calendar
inputdate ="08 05 2015"

MM=inputdate[:2]
DD=inputdate[3:5]
YY=inputdate[6:10]
MM=int(MM) # changed line
DD=int(DD) # changed line
YY=int(YY) # changed line
print(calendar.weekday(YY,MM,DD)) # prints out 2
```

Comment: Sorry i should have been more explicit. The commas need to be in the argument for the correct formatting as per the documentation states and also the data type for the three arguments needs to be integers (not accepting leading 0's as well). However the original input doesn't contain any commas so how would i go about writing the argument to contain these things with the input i provided.

Comment: Where does it say you need commas?  Are the commas used to separate the arguments?  Commas cannot be within ints so the argument would have to be converted to a string.

Comment: Converting to int removes leading 0's

Comment: i read that converting to int doesnt remove leading 0's in python? Also yes its for the arguments.

Comment: Ohhh i thought setting int(var) just changes the variable type. I didn't realise that you explicitly had to set it. Argghh ok thanks that fixes it. That also explains why inting variables didnt get rid of leading 0's. Thanks again.